# How to get a list of all cargo tests?

Tags: testing, rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to create a CI workflow which requires me to do both code coverage and ordinary testing. We run both at this time, because the coverage test instrumented for `grcov` can fail, but the normal test could pass. I want to automate comparing the test that failed in coverage instrumentation to the tests run without it. So for each test that failed in the `grcov` instrumentation I want to run a similar test without instrumentation.

Currently, the way to do it, is to hardcode the test paths, and/or use unreliable text-based testing detection. It's both labour intensive and not very reliable once people start adding more tests (which they will).

So my question is

1. Is there a way to get a list of all tests that are to be run from a multi-crate project.
2. Is there a way to attach actions to `cargo -test` if it fails, without stopping cargo test.
3. Is there a way to ask `cargo test` to only mention the names of failed tests (if any).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet for acting on `cargo test` results would be to use the unstable `--format json` option. It will output events in a JSON Lines format:

```
cargo test -- -Zunstable-options --format json
```

```json
{ "type": "suite", "event": "started", "test_count": 2 }
{ "type": "test", "event": "started", "name": "tests::my_other_test" }
{ "type": "test", "event": "started", "name": "tests::my_test" }
{ "type": "test", "name": "tests::my_test", "event": "ok" }
{ "type": "test", "name": "tests::my_other_test", "event": "failed", "stdout": "thread 'tests::my_other_test' panicked at 'assertion failed: false', src/lib.rs:20:9\nnote: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace\n" }
{ "type": "suite", "event": "failed", "passed": 1, "failed": 1, "ignored": 0, "measured": 0, "filtered_out": 0, "exec_time": 0.003150667 }
```

You can save that to a file and use another utility like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse out the relevant data. Here are some examples that might be helpful to you.

**Get all the tests that were ran:**

```
jq -c 'select(.type=="test" and .event=="started") | .name' <test-output.json
```

```json
"tests::my_other_test"
"tests::my_test"
```

**Get all the tests that failed:**

```
jq -c 'select(.type=="test" and .event=="failed") | .name' <test-output.json
```

```json
"tests::my_other_test"
```